# Eclipse Cocos2d-x app not change after changing the source

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I am working with Eclipse using cocos2d-x 3.4 the problem is when I changing code in cpp files under "Class" folder nothing is changes when I start the app. But the changes are applied in Visual studio also when I change java files changes  applied too. Any ideas whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the **[your_project]/proj.android/build_native.py** script is executed before you launch the android application.